# How to block a screen shot in an iOS application

Tags: ios, screenshot, netflix

I want to build a application in which I want to block screen shot by user like in Netflix application, it should return a black screen shot as in Netflix. Right now I am unable to get anything regarding this.

I don't know how Netflix is handling this?

Is there any way to detect captured image in the block and we can make it obscured?

Answer (score 8):

Netflix (and other providers) use "FairPlay Streaming" which is what prevents capture of the video content - link: https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/

Note that you ***can*** do a screen-shot of the Netflix UI (menus and such), just not the streaming content.

If you do a little searching, you will find plenty of discussion explaining that you ***cannot*** block screen captures in iOS.

Comment: @DongMag thanks for the answer but I am asking that how I can change or make the screenshot image black like Netflix. What technique they are using to do that,

Comment: @ManjodhSingh - I gave you the answer. It's part of Apple's "FairPlay Streaming" tech. If you try to screen-record / screen-capture, iOS saves the file with only black content  -- Netflix isn't doing anything. I'm adding a link in my answer where you can learn all about it. Other than that, your app has no control over screen captures.