# How To stop iOS App to take screenshot in react-native

Tags: ios, react-native

Is there any Possible way to prevent ios app to prevent screenshot like Netflix do.
Need help.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58416620/6257435

Comment: You can't - and it would be pointless because you can always take a screen shot using a second phone. You can get a notification after the fact.

Comment: @gnasher729 no it is not pointless. User take screenshot using another device is a different scenario